# Problem connecting encrypted Buffalo external 500GB hard disk in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: hard-drive, encryption

I am having problems connecting my Buffalo external 500GB hard disk in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The HDD is password protected and when I connect it on my PC, it just shows up the CD icon on the launcher. It works perfectly with Windows XP and Windows 7. Ii is preloaded with the password software - Utility_HD-PXTU, so whenever I connect it it first asks for the password. But in Ubuntu it is showing

```
unable to mount Utility_HD-PXTU
Error mounting: mount: /dev/sr2 already mounted or /media/Utility_HD-PXTU busy
```

and when I click on the CD icon it open a folder with some files on it

```
Error mounting: mount: block device /dev/sr2 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Comment: Does it need a Windows program to enter the password? How did you password protect the drive? If you used some software that came with it, it is probably a Windows program. What happens when you click on the CD icon? Please add more information by editing your original question.

Comment: Connect the drive to Windows, remove the password, and try connecting to Ubuntu.

Comment: now it is showing more details in the error please look into it

Comment: I'm fairly sure this drive just uses the ATA security specifications. With the right hdparm/sdparm commands you could unlock it, I think. However, I don't own such a hard drive, so this is mostly just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could gather from the Internet, Buffalo uses proprietary software that runs on Windows to encrypt the hard drive.   **It won't work with Ubuntu or any non-windows operating system.**

As @mitch says in comments you have to remove the password and encryption using Buffalo's **Secure Lock Manager**. An unencrypted drive will work in both Windows and Ubuntu.

If you want to encrypt some files that you will only use in Windows, see Secure Lock Manager documentation on how to encrypt a part of the hard drive. This part will not be available to Ubuntu, but at least you will be able to use a part of the hard drive in Ubuntu.

Hope this helps

Comment: @gurmeet You are welcome. If you think this answer is correct, please accept it as the correct answer and put a green tick mark next to it. This will help others who may have the similar problems later.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with WD HDD. WD Software does not work on Linux.
What I did: I removed password and I access it normally from Windows as well from Linux.
 However now you need to encrypt files that are stored on external drive:
I suggest using 7z. In manual you have example how to do it:
 On Linux/Unix, in order to backup directories you must use tar :
        - to backup a directory  :

> > tar cf - directory | 7za a -si directory.tar.7z

You just need to add -p flag to make it password protected.
I hope it will give you some clues how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypted Buffalo HDDs only work with Windows OS. But there is a trick to unlock encryped partition on linux:

> - Install XP/7/8 on virtualbox
> - Attach the HDD to virtual machine (device --> usb --> hdd)
> - A virtual CD will appear in VM, open password.exe, input your password
> - Encrypted partition appears in Linux

It works for me.